# X is not a function in onClick

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a basic loop:

```
    markers.forEach((marker) => {
      marker.addListener('click', this.openInfoWindow(marker));
    })
```

I have a TypeScript function declared as:

```
openInfoWindow(marker) { }
```

I am getting:

> zone-evergreen.js:172 Uncaught TypeError: this.openInfoWindow is not a
>   function
>       at some.component.ts:147
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at Di. (some.component.ts:145)
>       at ne.H
>       at Object.*.N.trigger
>       at re
>       at Di.*.O.set
>       at Di.setZoom
>       at map.js:29
>       at xw.T (map.js:41)

Why is this occuring?  What is wrong with my `click` call that would result in TypeScript not seeing this function?

Comment: `this` is not referring to what you think it is. Invoke it like this `marker.addListener('click', this.openInfoWindow(marker).bind(this))`

Comment: How are you calling that code? Where from?

Comment: @VLAZ  I'm calling it from another regular function.  However, the originating call comes from `ngOnInit`.

Comment: Can you include how you are invoking it along with the ngOnInit method

Comment: @NicholasK Too much code, I have tried to provide a simplified test case as this is the only code that matters here, the rest is all unrelated.  It's just a call chain, `ngOnInit` calls `function1` which calls `function2` which tries to do this.

Comment: Can you do a `console.log(this)` before the addEventListener? There is a problem with `this` I believe.

Comment: and dont you think it should be a function , not a function call? in addListener

Comment: @NicholasK It's a complex object, I suppose I could post a screenshot of it but I can't post text on it.

Comment: What object is it? Is it the global object?

Comment: @Patrick we're gonna need the whole function-calling chain in order to help you, I guess. You lose the scope somewhere in there and if any of proposed solutions won't work, the error is probably somewhere else in that chain.

Comment: Just want to point out that there is a difference between `addEventListener` and `addListener` (which you're using here) so it won't work the way you expect necessarily. 

The `addListener` is a google maps method in this case and can't be used in the same way as vanilla JS is my guess. I've struggled with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
 marker.addListener('click',this.openInfoWindow);
```

Function

```
openInfoWindow(event){
//access marker value from $event object
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, same result.

Comment: With that, I get a different error message:  "zone-evergreen.js:172 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined"

Comment: Hey can you paste the whole error here? example : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
    at XMLHttpRequest.desc.get [as ontimeout] (zone.js:1265)
    at XHRLocalObject.AbstractXHRObject._cleanup (abstract-xhr.js:149)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (abstract-xhr.js:125)
    at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn (zone.js:1230)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:398)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:165)
    at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:460)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it looses scope

Try this one

```js
markers.forEach((marker) => {
  marker.addListener('click', () => this.openInfoWindow(marker));
})
```

Comment: Same result with that, that was Supercool's original answer but he edited.

Comment: Looks like we need more information in this situation)

Comment: Could you provide a chain of calls until this code ?